# "Backbone is not defined" if I place Backbone code outside "$(function( ){ })" or "$(document).ready"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, frontend

I've just started learning Backbone, and right now here's my code:

```
$(function(){

    var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
       // whatever
    }); 

    new AppView();
});
```

When everything is inside the "$(function() {})" block, it works fine.  But I always make a habit of keeping my code in their own namespaces outside the executing block.

The problem is, when I move any of the code - whether it be the model, collection or view - it breaks and the browser logs warn me "Backbone is not defined."

EXAMPLE OF BREAKING CODE:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
   // whatever
}); 

$(function(){
    new AppView();
});
```

Sorry if this seems like a really obvious question to folks who already know Backbone, but is there a particular reason for this and is there a workaround for this?

EDIT: In response to Vincent, I'm not sure if this is what he meant, but I tried this and still got the same error:

```
var MyInitClass = {

    User : Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            name: 'user_name',
            email: 'user_email'
        }
    }),

    init : function() {
        new this.AppView();
    }

};

$(function(){
    MyInitClass.init();
});
```

SECOND EDIT:  Instead of manually linking to external backbone js like I did the first time, I included the 'backbone-rails' gem in my Gemfile and then added lines to require backbone and underscore in my application.js file.  Now everything's peachy.

Comment: "_EXAMPLE OF BREAKING CODE:_" where?

Comment: This isn't a Backbone-specific problem. It's almost certainly an order-of-operations problem. Show us how you're loading the library JS.

Comment: This is on a Rails web app. My HAML code for including Backbone js is:
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"
    = javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"
    = javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"
        = javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped out.  I fixed the problem - see my response to Vincent below.  Yes, I'm still a newbie and yes I'm still learning through trial and error.  :)

Comment: If you solved your question you should post an answer, not change your question. You can accept your own answer, and doing that will mark your question as answered in the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means that your backbone-min.js is not loaded when you try to execute the backbone code.

What you should do and what I usually do is that I created an initalizing class and I put `MyInitClass.init()` inside the `$(function() {})` block

Then in this `MyInitClass` you load data into your backbone models, create them and the associated views etc..

By executing code inside the `$(function() {})` block you are sure that your backbone file is loaded and ready to be used...

**Answering to question edit:**

You need to put your model creation in the init function like this:

```
var MyInitClass = {

init : function() {
    var user = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults : {
        name: 'user_name',
        email: 'user_email'
      }
    });
    new this.AppView();
}

};

$(function(){
    MyInitClass.init();
});
```

This is the kind of code I use in my app for users for instance:

```
if(!MyAppClass) var MyAppClass = {};
MyAppClass.users = (function($) {
    var user;

    var initialize = function() {
        user = new MyAppClass.Model.User();
        renderUser();
    };

    var renderUser = function() {
        var UserView = new MyAppClass.Views.UserView({
                model: user
        });
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };

})(jQuery);
```

And in your document ready block:

```
$(function(){
    MyAppClass.users.initialize()
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a shot at this Vincent.  I actually fixed the issue by installing the 'backbone-rails' gem and then requiring backbone and underscore in my application.js file.  Now everything's working just fine.